# Javascript match(), regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to search for the 1st occurence of a string in an html document that contains the following symbols: "Inbox (15)". I wrote the following expression which returns null, though:

```
var openTickets = document.body.innerHTML.match(/Inbox\s\((d+)\)/);
```

I only need the number (in the example above, it's 15) for further manipulations which is why I put it between capturing parentheses; I also escaped the "(" symbol (should have I?) as it's also present in the string.

Could anyone please help me get the regEx work? Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rMAHC/ as Suggested by @Grallen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're simply missing the escape sequence for numbers. Where you have `d+`, you want `\d+`.

Unless you need to support whitespace characters other than space (tab, newline, etc), I would just use

```
/Inbox \((\d+)\)/
```

#### Update

I think this might perform a little better as you can eliminate the HTML tags and just parse the text

```
var rx = /Inbox \((\d+)\)/;
var str = document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText;

var num = rx.test(str) && rx.exec(str)[1];
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/rMAHC/2/

Answer (score -2):

use this one:

```
document.body.innerHTML.match(/Inbox\s+\([0-9]+\)/);
```

Comment: You're also missing the capturing group for the number which is what the OP is actually after